# Check SSL certificate against CRL when an intermediate CA is in the way

Tags: openssl, crl

I am trying to understand how to check an SSL certificate, taking into account any relevant published CRL when the certificate chain is the following:

- Root CA (with no CRL distribution points)

  - Intermediate CA (advertising a CRL distribution point signed by the root CA)

    - Website certificate (advertising a CRL DP signed by the intermediate CA)

So, two CRL lists need to be checked.

It happens that BBC's website is configured as indicated above, so let's take this as an example. The files that I used are at the end of this question.

When I try to verify the certificate without checking the CRL, it's fine:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile intermediate_fullchain.pem bbc.pem
bbc.pem: OK
```

When I try to check the CRL from the CRL URLs given in the certificates, I get an error:

```
$ openssl verify -crl_download -crl_check_all -CAfile intermediate_fullchain.pem bbc.pem
Error loading CRL from http://crl.globalsign.com/gsrsaovsslca2018.crl
C = GB, ST = London, L = London, O = British Broadcasting Corporation, CN = www.bbc.com
error 3 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get certificate CRL
error bbc.pem: verification failed
```

This makes sense to me as the crl files are in DER format while openssl wants PEM format, so let's download the CRLs and convert them to PEM. The CRL URLs can be found using:

```
$ openssl x509 -in bbc.pem -text -noout
$ openssl x509 -in intermediate_fullchain.pem -text -noout
```

Then, I did:

```
$ wget -O intermediate_crl.der http://crl.globalsign.com/gsrsaovsslca2018.crl
$ openssl crl -inform DER -in intermediate_crl.der -outform PEM -out intermediate_crl.pem
$ wget -O root_crl.der http://crl.globalsign.com/root-r3.crl
$ openssl crl -inform DER -in root_crl.der -outform PEM -out root_crl.pem
```

Now, I thought I had everything I need to validate the certificate:

```
$ openssl verify -crl_check_all -CRLfile intermediate_crl.pem -CRLfile root_crl.pem -CAfile intermediate_fullchain.pem bbc.pem
OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R3, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
error 3 at 2 depth lookup: unable to get certificate CRL
error bbc.pem: verification failed
```

But, No! Verification still fails. My questions:

- What exactly is the issue in the command above? Does it mean OpenSSL expects the root CA to have a CRL?
- What is the right way to check the certificate against the two CRLs advertised in the CA chain?

## Files

`bbc.pem`: the webserver certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

`intermediate_fullchain.pem`: the intermediate CA certificate, with the chain to the root CA:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `intermediate_fullchain.pem` file doesn't contain a self-signed root.  I had to [download the correct one](https://valid.r3.roots.globalsign.com) from GlobalSign, although your machine may have it installed, in which case you simply need to remove the wrong intermediate from the above chain file.

You can view your intermediates with:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile intermediate_chain.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout
```

which gives:

```
subject=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign RSA OV SSL CA 2018
issuer=/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign

subject=/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
```

You need to replace the 2nd certificate in the chain with the Root CA certificate or remove it if your system has the Root installed.  It is this one that causes `openssl verify` to fail to find the CRL and therefore give you the error.

You can confirm the chain using the Subject and Authority Key Identifier extensions.  The Authority Key Identifier (AKI) of a certificate should be the Subject Key Identifier (SKI) of its signer (the CA). Therefore the AKI of the top-level BBC certificate is `F8:EF:7F:F2:CD:78:67:A8:DE:6F:8F:24:8D:88:F1:87:03:02:B3:EB` which is the SKI of the `C=BE, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, CN=GlobalSign RSA OV SSL CA 2018` intermediate CA.  The AKI of that CA certificate is `8F:F0:4B:7F:A8:2E:45:24:AE:4D:50:FA:63:9A:8B:DE:E2:DD:1B:BC` which is the SKI of `OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3, O=GlobalSign, CN=GlobalSign` - the Root CA linked in the first paragraph above.

However, to confuse matters, the 2nd intermediate certificate in your file also has a SKI and Subject which is the same as the root linked above, but isn't self-signed.  The AKI of that certificate is that of another Root CA certificate which you probably have in your trust-anchor store (my older test system doesn't have it, hence why it failed for me).  Without downloading the linked Root CA certificate, your path is therefore 4 certificates long (1 end-entity, 2 intermediates, and a root), which would therefore need three CRLs - the root's and one issued by each intermediate.

With the correct linked Root, I get:

```
openssl verify -crl_check_all -CRLfile all_crl.pem -CAfile intermediate_fullchain.pem bbc.pem
bbc.pem: OK
```

If you were to find the third CRL, then you should get the same result.

Comment: That's not it; I get the same error. Also, my man page (OpenSSL 1.1.1d-0+deb10u3 on Debian) also says about `-CRLfile` that `This option can be specified more than once to include CRLs from multiple files.`.

Comment: So it does.  It seems they changed the man page.

Comment: Oh, yes, there was one more certificate to reach the root! But I don't get why I should remove the second certificate in intermediate_fullchain.pem. It is part of the chain, and the CRL it contains should be checked. I think your last command works because the second cert is in the system files and the CRL is not checked. To simplify the problem, what would I have to do to make that command work even when adding the `-no-CAfile -no-CApath` switches? It should check none of the certificates in the chain has been revoked.

Comment: With the `-no-CAfile` and/or the `-no-CApath` switches you would need to provide all the certificates in the chain.  Please read my edit.